# Using VSTS Api -> get "ProfileNotFoundException"

Tags: azure-devops

I have successfully authenticated and can get the profile information for school/business accounts but when I test with a personal account is get ProfileNotFound Exception.

I'm using the following REST api:

```
GET  https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=1.0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you access to the VSTS account `https://account.visualstudio.com` to verify you can login? And what's the authorization type did you use for request the rest api, **basic auth** or **auth 2.0**?

Comment: Yeah I can login, I used auth 2.0.

Comment: What's the returned state? Can you add a screen shot for the rest api response?

Comment: i get "{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-TFS-ProcessId: 8d193c1b-d2c5-470b-9f79-8316f4d14b…}'

It's weird that it works with a business or education account.

Comment: What's the account did use used for return the 404? Isn't is business nor education accounts?

Comment: I get 404 on the personal account

Comment: What's the domain it ls? Is it a microsoft account like xx@outlook.com?

Comment: Yes it is @outlook.com

Comment: It can work with xx@outlook.com well. So please check what's the email you used when generating the auth token, is it consistent with the email address for your VSTS account?